# App crashes after integrating glide gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

> > My build.gradle file

App is working fine without adding Glide but when I add Glide for image loading it suddenly crashes on my first activity when app starts.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.animation.testdemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

> > Log Crash :

```
02-24 16:09:57.354 10475-10475/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.animation.testdemo, PID: 10475
                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.animation.testdemo-2/base.apk)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                       at com.animation.testdemo.activities.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:14)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
```

Have try to clen and build for many time but not find any proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2730) in glide's repo you should:

- use appcompat-v7:27.0.2 & glide:4.4.0+

So just update the compile SDK to 27 and the support library. It will fix your problem :)

If you need to keep the version for any reason you can exclude the dependency as described [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991). In your gradle file:

```
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    you got this error because glide version 4.6.1 using targetSdkVersion 27, and you are using targetSdkVersion 26.. 

    try changing your 
    compileSdkVersion 26

    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    targetSdkVersion 27
 or
    try lower version of glide : 
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
```